# How to anonymize/mask part of string in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

Say I am creating a pie chart for customer called 'Air Holland', for this customer I would like to show the overlap with other customers in a pie chart, including customers called 'Air Hungary', 'Air Ireland' and 'Air Iceland'. Due to privacy regulations of my customers I can only show partial names, e.g. the first three or four letters of their name. 'Air Holland' thus changes to 'Air xxxxxxx'

To implement this now in my pie chart, I have created a new Column CustomerNameMasked that takes the customer name, and replaces all characters but the first four with an 'x'. Ideally I would like to use CustomerName as the Legend in my pie chart, and then the CustomerNameMasked as the label, such that the pie chart is created using CustomerName, but will show the masked names.

However, as far as I know such a label is not possible, so now I have used CustomerNameMasked as my Legend column. But since these name are not unique (e.g. 'Air Hungary' and 'Air Holland' are both 'Air xxxxxxx' in the CustomerNameMasked column), different customers are taken together.

Any ideas how to create unique masked customer names? Or another work-around to ensure that my pie chart correctly shows the data per customer, but the legend shows masked names?

Comment: How about adding a unique index / displaying the Customer ID instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of preventing anonymised names from being merged in visualisations is to make sure they are not the same.

---

Add a calculated column:

```
Anonymised = "Airline " & RANKX('MyTable','MyTable'[CustomerName],,ASC,Dense)
```

Result:

```
Airline 1
Airline 2
Airline 3
...
```

---

If you prefer `x`'s:

Add a `Anonymised_Name` table,

```
Name             Anonymised Name
"Air Holland"    "Air xxxxxxx"
"Air Hungary"    "Air xxxxxxx "
"Air Iceland"    "Air xxxxxxx  "
```

Use "fake space" (alt+0160 on the numpad) to prevent PowerBI from swallowing it up. Add a relationship and use this column in visualisations.

I prefer previous option as it makes it easier to distinguish and keep track of individual customers.

---

If you don't care whether number of "x"s matches real name:

```
Anonymised_Name_2 = "Air XXXXXXX" & REPT(" ", 
  RANKX('MyTable','MyTable'[CustomerName],,ASC,Dense))
```

(again fake space alt+0160)

---

Depending on what you do with your report, there is a significant risk of real customer names "leaking", so ideally you would want to anonymize your data before importing it.

Comment: Hi @user5226582, thank you for your answer. However, I already managed to create a calculated column, and my question is not so much how to create a mask. My question is rather: how to make a pie chart using the unmasked columns, while making sure I can only see masked customer names

Comment: Not sure you can. My answer explains how to create anonymised name which won't be "taken together" when you use it in visualisations.

Comment: Yeah I understand, thanks for taking your time. The first option your describe ('Airline 1' etc.) is indeed unique, but is fully anonymous which is not wanted, I still want a partial mask to be able to identify customers when you have inside-knowledge. The second option, however, does not give me unique masked customer names, so that won't help I think!

Comment: Just append different number of spaces and it will be unique.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that and although I don't like it from a esthetic point of view, it might be the best work-around! Thanks!