# PowerBI DrillThrough Pass different parameter

Tags: powerbi, drillthrough

So I have a report from where I want to drill through a different report.

The problem is that the Title field used as display repeats on different entries, Like this I need to drill by the ID (the only unique field), but this ID field is hard to read for the User.

how can I pass the ID from the selected column on the first report to the second report?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540718/how-to-anonymize-mask-part-of-string-in-powerbi/46541361#46541361) may be helpful. Just generate new IDs, friendlier to the user.

Comment: Thank you ! that's a really creative idea, the white spaces option is something  I have used also in SharePoint to handle ID issues 

Thank you !

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding white spaces helped solve the issue of the ID generation as there is currently no way for PowerBi to have the same title in different columns or dril through child columns

thanks to @user5226582